# What files absolutely belong in a SFDX repository?

Tags: salesforcedx, git

So - with SFDX there are tons of files being generated. Default files like `gitattributes` should obviously go there, `package.xml` already seems to be handled differently and then there are files `.prettierrc` and tons of `json` files. I'm originally coming from the Microsoft world and there are tons of files generated that absolutely do NOT belong into a repository. But here - I'm really confused by all of them. Can somebody hint me in the right direction? Maybe there's a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is "required" depends on what you intend to do. If you want to use VS Code and the entire suite of what's possible, you need all but two of the files. If you just want to replace Ant scripts, you only need approximately three files (with an absolute minimum of one; the first one listed below). I'll go over the files created in 7.63, and why you need the files. Feel free to remove any files you don't think you need.

## sfdx-project.json

This file is used to control the API version of the project, file paths to push/pull/deploy/retrieve from, Unlocked Packages and Dependencies, mdapi and source conversion commands, etc. You really want this file to exist.

Required for many commands.

## .forceignore

This allows the push/pull/status commands to ignore certain files when using Source Tracking. The default file has the minimum recommended configuration.

Required only for Scratch Org/Source Tracking, optional otherwise.

## config\project-scratch-def.json

You need a Scratch Org Definition File to create Scratch Orgs. It is also used to enable Feature Dependencies for Unlocked Packages.

Required for Scratch Orgs or Unlocked Packages with Feature Dependencies, optional otherwise.

## force-app\main\default\lwc.eslintrc.json

This configures ESLINT to properly check your LWC (Lightning Web Components) files for syntax problems without deploying to Salesforce. The CLI requires this file to deploy/push/pull/retrieve LWC.

Required if you want to use LWC, optional otherwise.

## .vscode\extensions.json

## .vscode\launch.json

## .vscode\settings.json

## .eslintignore

All used by VS Code and/or the Salesforce DX Bundle.

Required if you plan on using VS Code and/or some package.json scripts. Other IDEs may or may not need these files, or alternative files. Otherwise optional.

## .prettierignore

## .prettierrc

Tells Prettier how to behave when formatting source code, and files to ignore.

Required if you want to use Code Formatting in VS Code, optional otherwise.

## scripts\soql\account.soql

## scripts\apex\hello.apex

Demo files that are absolutely not required for any core functionality. It may be nice to have a copy of them to refer to, but nothing will break without them.

Optional.

## README.md

The readme for the project; it typically states how to install/push/deploy/build/whatever, core features, etc.

*Technically* Optional, but Very Highly Recommended for any non-trivial project.

## .gitignore

Used to keep certain files out of a Git repo. Some files are not portable or only needed during building, and may leak sensitive information like authentication keys.

*Technically* Optional, but Very Very Highly Recommended if you use Git, especially if you plan on going Open Source.

## package.json

This is used to automatically install dependencies for modules used by Node, tracks configuration scripts, etc.

Required for VS Code Salesforce DX Bundle. Recommended for bonus CLI scripts.

Comment: Great list! Still needs some research from my side - especially since I'm not using VS Code - but this is a great start. Thanks!