# How to create new Illuminated Cloud project from git repo

Tags: salesforcedx, git, illuminatedcloud

Which files should I include in my git repository for creating a new Illuminated Cloud project ?

Comment: can you be more specific on where you're stuck or whether there's files you're unsure of including? As long as your repo has whatever `sfdx` needs and not necessarily what VS Code needs (see this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310493/what-files-absolutely-belong-in-a-sfdx-repository)), then Illuminated Cloud will create the rest of the files it needs based on identifying it as a sfdx project once you create from version control in IntelliJ

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I mean files , which required and  Illuminated Cloud with them will can create rest of the files

Comment: The best resource for Illuminated Cloud support is their [Google group](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/g/qanda).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sfdx force:project:create -n myProjectName` will create a VS Code-based project.

Of these, you only **need** `sfdx-project.json`. Everything else is optional, depending on your needs.

Consult the following table for each of the files

| Required | Recommended | Name | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No | Yes | config/project-scratch-def.json | A good starting file for Scratch Orgs |
| No | Yes | README.md | Documentation |
| **Yes** | **Yes** | sfdx-project.json | Required for SFDX to operate at all |
| No | *VSC | .vscode/extensions.json | Used only for VS Code |
| No | *VSC | .vscode/launch.json | Used only for VS Code |
| No | *VSC | .vscode/settings.json | Used only for VS Code |
| No | Yes | force-app/main/default/lwc/.eslintrc.json | Used by ESLINT on any platform |
| No | Yes | force-app/main/default/aura/.eslintrc.json | Used by ESLINT on any platform |
| No | No | scripts/soql/account.soql | Sample SOQL file |
| No | No | scripts/apex/hello.apex | Sample Execute Anonymous File |
| No | Yes | .eslintignore | Used by ESLINT to control which file it attempts to generate errors for |
| No | Yes | .forceignore | Used by SFDX to determine files to ignore for push/pull/etc. |
| No | Yes | .gitignore | Default files to ignore in git commits |
| No | Yes | .prettierignore | Used to control files Prettier will skip |
| No | Yes | .prettierrc | Prettier configuration settings |
| No | Yes | package.json | NPM package file |

The `.vscode` files are the only ones you'd only want in VS Code, all the others you can choose depending on what features you plan on using. Note that this is not so much a recommendation for your IDE, but simply in general. If you want to share your project with others who may use VS Code or another IDE, it's recommended you just commit all the recommended files.

Illuminated Cloud will generate any additional files it needs aside from these. You can choose to commit those files, or not, depending on your project's needs.

Comment: Thank you  so much

Comment: +1, but is this table in some documentation or of your own creation?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves The recommendations are my own, and not those of salesforce.com or any other entity I'm aware of. These recommendations come from my experience with DX since the open beta (and it's definitely polished up nicely since then). I've built dozens of packages so far, ranging from raging successes to abysmal failures. As far as I'm aware, there's no documentation that goes as far as this answer does, probably in part because DX is still evolving; I fully expect this list to be eventually outdated.

Comment: @sfdcfox - definitely very useful and was just thinking it might be a good thing to have in a community qa where we can all help to keep it up to date.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves You've got a point. I'll go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in the FAQ here:

http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/support/faq#ProjectVersionControl

Please let me know if you have any other questions after reviewing that information.